# How to check if android checkbox is checked within its onClick method (declared in XML)?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, onclick

I have a checkbox in android which has the following XML:

```
<CheckBox
   android:id="@+id/item_check"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:onClick="itemClicked" />
```

This is my onClick() method in my Activity class.

```
public void itemClicked(View v) {
  //code to check if this checkbox is checked!
}
```

I am aware that we can create an object of the checkbox and assign id to it. But is there a better way to achieve the functionality when declaring `onClick` method via XML?

Comment: ((CheckBox)v).isChecked();

Answer (score 112, accepted):

try this one :

```
public void itemClicked(View v) {
  //code to check if this checkbox is checked!
  CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v;
  if(checkBox.isChecked()){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This will do the trick:

```
  public void itemClicked(View v) {
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
           "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Fees Paid Rs100:"
      android:textColor="#276ca4"
      android:checked="false"
      android:onClick="checkbox_clicked" />
```

> Main Activity from here

```
   public class RegistA extends Activity {
CheckBox fee_checkbox;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_regist);
 fee_checkbox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);// Fee Payment Check box
}
```

> checkbox clicked

```
     public void checkbox_clicked(View v)
     {

         if(fee_checkbox.isChecked())
         {
            // true,do the task 

         }
         else
         {

         }

     }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this code:

```
public void itemClicked(View v) {
 //code to check if this checkbox is checked!
 if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
   // code inside if
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@BindView(R.id.checkbox_id) // if you are using Butterknife
CheckBox yourCheckBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity); 
    yourCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);// If your are not using Butterknife (the traditional way)

    yourCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            yourObject.setYourProperty(yourCheckBox.isChecked()); //yourCheckBox.isChecked() is the method to know if the checkBox is checked
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: yourCheckBox = " + yourObject.getYourProperty() );
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously you have to make your XML with the id of your checkbox :

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your label"
    />
```

So, the method to know if the check box is checked is : `(CheckBox) yourCheckBox.isChecked()` it returns `true` if the check box is checked.