# Two state UI component with "can be checked" functionality

Tags: android, user-interface

I need two state (checked / default) UI component which can be validated from code, is it possible to check it.

Checkbox is ok, but I do not have any way to check is it ok to check it.

So something like that:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked) {
            // Check if it is possible to check this
            // e.g return false, not possible to check
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get what do you mean by `"can be checked"`. Of course `it can always be checked`, unless you don't **disable** it.

Comment: I want to have functionality to check is it possible to check it at the time user clicks e.g. checkbox

Comment: It **is** possible to un/check it ALWAYS.

Comment: Yep, but ultimately I want to validate, is it ok to be checked before it is actually checked. Maybe I do something like Sergii suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do smth like this: checkbox detect on click and than check if checked

In your layout:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/item_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="itemClicked" />
```

And after it in code:

```
public void itemClicked(View v) {
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v;
    if(checkBox.isChecked()){
        // logic 
    } else {

    }
}
```

Inspired [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336151/how-to-check-if-android-checkbox-is-checked-within-its-onclick-method-declared).

Comment: In onClick event, is Checkbox already checked because used tap it? Or is checkbox actually checked after onClick event?

Comment: @devha yes, checkbox will already have new state when `itemClicked(View v)` is called