# Why does checkbox.IsChecked() not return the checked state

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

From the ton of questions on SO about `isChecked()` not working in android, I have come to accept that to get the checked state of a `checkbox` you need to add a listener. But I was just wondering whether anyone knows why it doesn't work correctly, is it a bug? Am I misinterpreting the desired functionality?

For your reference here is some code.

```
            View itemView = adapter.getView(i, null, autoDiscoverListView);

            CheckBox selected = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbEnabled);

            if(selected.isChecked()){
                ...
            }
```

Here is the code in the getView which is related to the checkbox

```
        CheckBox cbEnabled = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbEnabled);
        cbEnabled.setChecked(item.getEnabled());

        cbEnabled.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean enabled) {
                ...
        }});
```

Comment: have you check by printing value of selected.isChecked() on sysout.. Logcat

Comment: can you post full code with xml?

Comment: It appears to be working... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336151/how-to-check-if-android-checkbox-is-checked-within-its-onclick-method-declared

Comment: by default it is unchecked ....thtsy returning false.. u must add listner

Comment: It appears that your CheckBox is in a ListView item layout. If you're getting the wrong checked state in some listener therein, we'll need to see your `getView()` method.

Comment: @MikeM. I've added the code for the checkbox in the getView now. That is exactly what I am doing, sorry I should have probably made that clear.

Comment: @koutuk I know that you need a listener to change it, but I want to know WHY isChecked does not return the correct state of the checked box. I have outputted isChecked to the log and they are all saying True even though two of the items are not checked

Comment: If checkbox is in listview, use settag method to set checked status and retrieve from that tag in the check change listener.

Comment: If the problem is occurring within the `onCheckedChanged()` method, make sure you're using `compoundButton.isChecked()` instead of `cbEnabled.isChecked()`. Or just check the `boolean` passed into that method.

Comment: Actually, which CheckBox's state are you wanting in that method? `cbEnabled`, or some other CheckBox?

Comment: @Keithin8a are you using Custom ListView ???

Comment: @MikeM. In the top piece of code I am trying to get a specific list view items checkbox.

Comment: @koutuk yes I am, I have a checkbox on the left, and a Title.

Comment: Link hope it will help you...http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Comment: How are you getting `itemView` in the first code block? If that code is outside of the Adapter - e.g., in an Activity - then that's probably not going to be reliable. It's probably preferable to change your underlying data class to include a `boolean` for the checked state, update it in the listener, and retrieve it from that, rather than from the Adapter or ListView.

Comment: @MikeM. Basically this form is looking in the file directory for xml files which contain items I am interested. I then display a list of items i have discovered and ask which ones they want to add to the database. I have an `add selected button` on the form and the code is in there. I have added the itemview code in the first block. Sorry I missed that hopefully you will be able to help more.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the root of your problem, if you're not somehow storing each item's selected state. You have a coupla options. 1) You could alter your data class, as I mentioned, to track each item's state, then just `get(i)` from the List you're passing to the Adapter. 2) Or, if you don't have a custom data class - e.g., you're just using a List of Strings - you can create a separate `List<Boolean>` in the Adapter, one-to-one with the data List, and create a `public` method in the Adapter to return the `Boolean` for a given `i` (assuming `i` is the position in the ListView).

Comment: @MikeM. OK, thanks for your help I think I get what I have to do. 

Would you be able to explain why it is not reliable outside of the adapter? when I look in itemView under the debugger everything is correct except the checked state of the checkbox. Is there some sort of delay between the adapter and the view?

Comment: Oh, no, actually I just noticed you may already have the mechanism I described in place. Assuming `item.getEnabled()` is the checked state, and you're properly updating it in the listener, then you just need to get that value from the `i`th item of whatever List `item` is in. Trying to get it from the View is circuitous, and error-prone, as you've seen. As to why it doesn't work when you do it that way, I'm not sure. I'd have to inspect the rest of your code.

Comment: @MikeM. I do and I don't. The getEnabled is used by a different view which uses this adapter. That is for the actual list of configurations after they have been added to the database they can be toggled on or off. I could potentially set that value and use that but from a readability point of view it could come across as confusing because technically there is nothing to be enabled or disabled. Thanks for your help so far it has been very useful. Feel free to add an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Agreed. You don't want to try to use that for two different meanings. Thanks. I'll post an answer a little later, when I've got time to write up a proper one. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made some mistake in code,Please try as below,

```
public void itemClicked(View v) {
        //code to check if this checkbox is checked!
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v;
        if(checkBox.isChecked()){

        }
    }
```

Comment: OK, so if I add an onClickListener then that does work correctly, but could you please edit the answer with what my mistake is? Why can't I get the checkbox by using `(CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbEnabled);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like.

//Returns the enabled status for this view. 
`selected.isEnabled()`  //return True if this view is enabled, false otherwise.

//Indicates whether the view is currently in pressed state.
`selected.isPressed()` //return True if this view is enabled, false otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if you look at my code then hopefully it is clear that I am using is enabled and my problem is that this is returning true even when it is false. Sorry if my question wasn't clear for you.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't check the state in the onCreate() of the class.

Comment: i'm not, sorry I don't understand where you have made these assumptions, to better word my post would you please tell me how you have come to the conclusions that you have. I thought it was pretty obvious but clearly not.

Answer (score 0):

I know that method `isChecked`() works, normally. I suspect you're not getting the correct view. For now, I have only one suggestion, and since I don't know your code well.

```
View itemView = adapter.getView(i, null, convertView);
```

Note: This code references the View object `convertView` when you set the listener. At least `convertView` works for the listener.