# how to change a GONE visibility to VISIBLE visibility in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

In my application, I set my Frame Layout visibility to GONE, and I want to show the Frame layout when i click a check box. would it be possible to set it VISIBLE ?

xml:this is the entire xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
style="@style/Container">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/red_logo"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Marchant Offer"
    android:textSize="30px"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerCountry"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Country" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerState"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="State/Province" />

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextCity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="City"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextAirport"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Neareast Airport"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerCategory"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Category" />


</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editSTextOfferTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Offer Title"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextOfferSummary"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Offer Summary"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextOfferDescription"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Offer Description"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Offer Highlights"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Inclusion"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Others Inclusion"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do You Offer Inclusive Hotel/Port Pick-Up and Drop-off"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxYes"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yes"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxNo"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ifyes"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Your picking up coverage area"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Time to picking up the Guess"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Additional Info for Guess"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

java code:

```
checkBoxYes = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxYes);
checkBoxYes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
            frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `FrameLayout` height is `wrap_content` change it to `match_parent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes..

```
ch = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox);              
ch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
            framelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//framelayout is your layout,initially set GONE.
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: thank for the answer, but i have the same code with code above before, and it didin't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this way it will help you

```
private int checkedBoxs = 0;
private final CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = 
    new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                status.set(position, true);
                checkedBoxs++;
                if (layout.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                status.set(position, false);
                checkedBoxs--;
                if (checkedBoxs == 0)
                    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: sorry, but I have a bit confusing with this code, when should I declare the status and position ? sorry but this is my first time, so please lead me. thanks

Comment: what do you mean with position and status?

Comment: status.set(position, true). do we need to declare it first ?

Comment: first check for your status..use log for that..then put your visibility

Comment: to check checkbox checkd or not see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336151/how-to-check-if-android-checkbox-is-checked-within-its-onclick-method-declared

Comment: sorry for my stupid question again, what do u mean by use log ?

Comment: use this Log.d(TAG, "status of checkbox: " + yourvalue);

Comment: you can also use System.out .println();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because the views visibility inside your frame layout are also gone.

Try the below code

```
    checkBoxYes = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxYes);
    ViewGroup frameLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout)
    checkBoxYes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked){
        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         int count = frameLayout.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View view = frameLayout.getChildAt(i);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    }
}
```

});

Make sure that your frameLayout is cast to ViewGroup.

Comment: my frame layout does not empty. it contains Linear Layout and three Edit Text.

Comment: Have changed my answer. try it out.

Comment: where did u declare the mViewGroup ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I am declaring frameLayout as a ViewGroup. Instead of declaring it as a FrameLayout.

Comment: So it will be ViewGroup frameLayout instead of FrameLayout frameLayout

Comment: so, in XML i should change the FrameLayout to ViewGroup as well ?

Comment: No need to change there

Comment: All layouts are subclass of ViewGroup.

Comment: thanks for your answer but somehow it still does not working, I will think and do some resource about the other method. thanks

Comment: Why not show your entire xml i might be able to better help

Comment: i already re edit my xml code, hope u can help me though, thanks

Comment: Thank you for helping me guys, I already solve the issue, thank you for all of you

Comment: it is a shame, before my java class name is Marchant_Offer, so I create a new java class with name MarchantOffer(without underline) because I see the error in the log and I copy paste the code. It's solve all of the issue. I think android studio does not support any special character in the java class

Comment: It happens. Glad you figured it out. Happy coding.