# Android Studio App Crashes when CheckBox is checked

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi the app crashes when I check the checkbox, but it otherwise the program works

XML:

```
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/whippedCreamTopping"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
            />
```

Java:

```
    //This method is called when the order button is clicked.
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whippedCreamTopping);
        boolean hasWhippedCream = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();    
        int price = calculatePrice();
        String priceMessage = createOrderSummary(price, hasWhippedCream);
        displayMessage(priceMessage);   

    }


    //displays the given quantity value on the screen.
    private void displayQuantity(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }

    //Calculates the price of the order.
    private int calculatePrice() {
        return quantity * price;
    }

    //Add in a summary
        private String createOrderSummary(int price, boolean addWCream) {
        double priceTotal = calculatePrice();  
        String myName = "JJ Jobs";
        String priceString = "Name: " + myName;
        priceString += "\nAdd Whipped Cream?" + addWCream;
        priceString += "\nQuantity: " + quantity + "\nTotal: $" + priceTotal;
        priceString += "\nThank you";
        return priceString;
    } //end of createOrderSummary
```

I tried [How to check if android checkbox is checked within its onClick method (declared in XML)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336151/how-to-check-if-android-checkbox-is-checked-within-its-onclick-method-declared)
but I did not get the code (checkbox to work)

Comment: post logcat error log and also onCheckboxClicked method

Comment: you have view so why are u creating another new instance for checkbox

Comment: you need to post the error you are getting and the line number of error. Second, your checkbox method as per xml is 'onCheckboxClicked' but i cant find it in your java class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem inside the XML code:

```
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/whippedCreamTopping"

        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"  *I removed this line of code 
                                             *then it worked
        />
```

Thank you for all the help